# HTACCESS Subdomain to folder with index.php instead of .html

Tags: .htaccess, dns, directory

I have configured webserver to access a subfolder (sub_blog) by a subdomain (blog.mydomain.com) using this htaccess rules

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond $1 !^sub_
RewriteRule (.*) /sub_blog/$1 [L]
```

The problem is that if i want to put an index.php page instead of index.html, i can't when i connect to blog.mydomain.com i got a 404 error page (index.html not found)

How can i fix this? Should i add virtual host? If yes, how to do this?

/sub_blog/.htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: why rewrite? you can set a default document on any directory you want. just add index.php as a default for your subdir.

Comment: Already tried, not working.

Answer (score 0):

You just need `DirectoryIndex` directive at top of your .htaccess to load `index.php` as default.

Try this code in root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /sub_blog/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^sub_blog/
RewriteRule (.+) /sub_blog/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Already tried, not working. It's like when i type blog.mydomain.com that requests blog.mydomain.com/index.html

Can you also try with that rule and check if i made a mistake?

Comment: Added, same problem. Do you know althernative way (like VirtualHosts) to do this?

Comment: try updated code in site root's .htaccess (replacing your existing code)

Comment: There is another DirectoryIndex index.php.

Can you check if is my problem or rule problem?